# Using Rigid Body to push something out of a flapped box

Tags: armature, bones, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have a flapped box, and I want to lift an object out of it, forcing the flaps to open as it pushes against them.

Here's my sphere failing to open the flaps:
[image: example]

I have seen [an answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82160/rigid-body-box-flaps), but building the flaps as separate objects means they won't look like they are attached to the cube part of the box.

My box flaps have armatures - one bone for each flap, as created in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1em_ijMvUk&list=PLgnT48dGUuO0Ok7qgi2cly9DDcXNm8hSG&index=24&t=412s).

I found another [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0haYapQ7l_U) explaining how to use the ["rigid bodys generator" add-on](https://github.com/12funkeys/rigid_bodys_gen), but it hasn't been updated to work with Blender 3.x

Is there a way to use armature bones as passive hinged rigid bodies? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the simplest thing, that is make constraints between multiple objects, and then parent your armatures bones to those objects, like such:[image]

After adding the bone constraints, you'll need to repose your bones.

The final result looks like this:

[image]